# Validate currency code matches one of the allowed values

Tags: java, validation, java-money, jsr354

I have a POJO, which contains a field called `price`.

The field's type is `javax.money.MonetaryAmount`, so that I can benefit from JSR 354 validation etc.

I have a constraint on the field specifying that the currency must be `EUR`:

```
@Currency("EUR")
```

How can I specify that the currency must be either `EUR` or `USD`?

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Columns;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Currency;
import org.jadira.usertype.moneyandcurrency.moneta.PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency;

import javax.money.MonetaryAmount;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "persistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency", typeClass = PersistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency.class)
public class LocalizedProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Currency("EUR")
    // @Currency("EUR, USD") .. doesn't work
    @Columns(columns = {
            @Column(name = "amount_currency", length = 3),
            @Column(name = "amount_value", precision = 19, scale = 5)})
    @Type(type = "persistentMoneyAmountAndCurrency")
    private MonetaryAmount price;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MonetaryAmount getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(MonetaryAmount price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The annotation supports `String[]` as `value`: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Currency.java

Though you can simply use `@Currency({"EUR", "USD"})`